# How to store Soap Response Message in a string using citrus framework

Tags: java, soap, citrus-framework

I have a situation where I need to store my SOAP response in a string in case of success.

```
soap(soapActionBuilder -> soapActionBuilder.client("xyzclient").receive().messageType(MessageType.XML).validate("xapth validation", "Success"));
```

The above code is working if we receive a success response, but now I need to store that SOAP response in a string and return it.

I am not sure how I can do that. if anyone is having any idea please share, I am new to citrus. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you need the whole SOAP response as a String? What would you like to do with this string response?

Comment: Hi @Omeniq Thanks for the response. Actually I need t capture a node value from the reponse xml and then store it in a string and then that value should be validated in the UI. But if I am able to store the whole response, that should also be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to capture some value from response body, you could use a method `extractFromPayload`. This methods takes two parameters:

1. `path` - path to XML element
2. `variable` -  to store element into variable for further usage in citrus test.

Sample how to use it:

```
soap().client("client")
.receive()
.extractFromPayload("//Foo/bar","foobar");
```

Now you can use variable foobar like this `${foobar}`

```
echo("Extracted var: ${foobar}")
```